# Connecting fingerprint biometric device to desktop

Tags: networking, biometrics

I want to access the contents of the biometric device using a command prompt or a shared folder instead of using the software that comes with it. I am new in networking, I did the following:

```
    1. Set a static IP to my biometric device: 192.168.1.201 port 4370 (default)
    2. configure ethernet in my PC using ip: 192.168.1.1, subnet 255.255.255.0
    3. Connected my PC to the device using crossover cable.
```

The device is pingable, my firewall is off. I cannot access the device in browser http://192.168.1.201, or in directory \\192.168.1.201

I am planning to create a vbscript or a php code to access the biometric instead of the software that comes with it. So as a requirement, I need to have access to the device

Comment: You should state what the device's make and model is. It's probably using some proprietary protocol.

Comment: Fortress TA-TX628 LAN (Webserver)... I have no idea how to connect. I tried telnet and it asks for credentials that I dont have:
  Welcome to Linux (ZMM220) for MIPS
  Kernel 3.0.8 on an MIPS
  (none) login:
  password:

Comment: Have you tried to point your browser to http://192.168.1.201:4370/ ?
As you wrote, 4370 is the default port, maybe the web server listens on that port.

Comment: Forget port 4370 - looks like that's a proprietary protocol port. Search the internet for "ZK technologies", they seem to be the manufacturer, the devices are sold under different names by different distributors. It's weird that port 80 (web) does not work - that should be available at least.

Answer (score 3):

You can not access the biometric machine through telnet. The username and password is set by the manufacturer. They will use the telnet account credentials only for their internal development and testinng purpose. @Hans-Martin Mosner, machine can well connect with port 80. Only thing is software will not listen at port 80 as it has been bound with http. If you remove the port 80 from listening for http then you can make your application to connect with port 80

If you are trying for accessing the biometric machines to associate with your web application, go for CAMSUnit machines. CAMS provides the [WEB APIs](http://www.etscouncil.com/login?mailerResponse=true&orn=Quora&ts=25/02/2017&ornr=%22https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740510/connecting-fingerprint-biometric-device-to-desktop%22&tpc=Stackoverflow&it=CAMS-API&learnref=http://camsunit.com/#api) for their biometric machines. It supports registering the callback URL which gets called every time new attendance gets registered.